# Observing Realm notifications while app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have an app that uses realm and I have my VC class set up to observe changes in the realm, and when a change occurs in the realm, triggers a local push notification:

```
self.notificationToken = YPB.realmSynced.observe { _,_ in
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    self.notifyOf(self.requests.first!) // creates a local user notification
                }
```

This works beautifully, but the `notificationToken` closure only gets called when the app is in the foreground. Is there a way to have this work with the app in the background? Ideally using local UNNotifications...

Thank you

Comment: See [Realm notifications on background threads with Swift](https://academy.realm.io/posts/realm-notifications-on-background-threads-with-swift/). Just as a side note: there's no such thing as a local push notifications, by definition push notifications are coming from a server.

Comment: I actually did see that article before but I wasn't sure if "Background" simply meant "off the main queue" but I'll give it a whirl! Thansk!

Comment: @DávidPásztor this solution worked and I'm very excited! I'd love to mark your response as an answer, so would you like to post it as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. However, I posted my comment as a comment for a reason, providing a link to an off-site tutorial is not an answer here on SO, so it wouldn't be fair to post is as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for that information. I've discovered that when I hit Stop in Xcode, the background notifications don't work, even though the app is still running on my iPad. I'm relatively new to programming so I'm probably missing something very basic about how all of this works, but is this cause for worry?

Comment: If you start the app on you iPad itself, this issue shouldn’t come up.

Comment: Well I'm not sure how to do that. I believe I tried killing the app and then clicking on it on the iPad, which I imagine would be the way, but I don't think it worked. Can't test it right now, I'm onto another issue, you'll see my new post...

Comment: Just open the app on your iPad as you would with any app installed from the AppStore.